# CORS enabled, but adding cookies in header causes request to be blocked? I have enabled CORS with credentials server side, not sure how to solve this

Tags: http, firefox, cors, relay, relaymodern

Using express-session so need cookie id for authentication, but even with setting up CORS correctly (or what I thought to be) on front and back end I'm still getting issues. CORS is working without cookies enabled.

**Backend config**

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  credentials: true,
};
```

**Frontend config** (using Relay)

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4002/graphql", {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "include", // Allow cookies to be sent
  headers: {
    Authorization: `*/*`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
```

**If I do not include credentials** the response shows that CORS cookies are allowed:
[image]

However, as soon as I enable credentials in the client fetch config, the request is blocked. There is no response, I think Firefox is blocking the req before it is sent?
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Look at the Console. If the request is being blocked by CORS rules then it should tell you why there.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was not setting the accepted CORS origins to "*", as said in the console (thanks Quentin).